# Пустые поля Subject и To в письме, полученном с помощь JavaMail

Tags: java, javamail

*Это переведённый вопрос [JavaMail - Subject and To fields are empty in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771134/javamail-subject-and-to-fields-are-empty-in-email), а также переведённый и дополненный ответ на него.*

Столкнулся с проблемой получения писем при помощи JavaMail. Сообщения успешно отправляются и принимаются, но тема письма и список получателей приходят пустыми (равно как и прочие заголовки письма).

Вот метод отправки писем. Я не изменял системные свойства, они должны иметь значение по умолчанию:

```
public void sendEmail(String[] ToEmailAddr, String Subject, String Body) {

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(fMailServerConfig, null);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < ToEmailAddr.length; i++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(ToEmailAddr[i]));
        }
        message.setSubject(Subject);
        message.setText(Body);
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        logger.error("Cannot send email. " + ex);
    }
}
```

Как корректно получить тему и список получателей письма?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, проблема заключалась в конфликте библиотек. Tomcat включает свою реализацию JavaMail как runtime-зависимость при сборке веб-приложения через Maven.  Для того, чтобы решить проблему, нужно исключить `geronimo-javamail` из списка зависимостей в `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Чтобы определить, какая из библиотек тянет за собой `geronimo-javamail`, нужно получить список зависимостей Maven, включая runtime-зависимости:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=runtime
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не отметить ответ, как верный?